# Js Crear multiple instancia en export default

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estoy teniendo un problema, funciona correctamente en la primera llamada a `Paginator` el problema es al volver a llamarla en un cambio de pagina.

> Clase Paginator

```
const Paginator = {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  },
  data(data) {
    this.data = data;
    return this;
  },
  page(number) {
    this.page = number;
    this.data = this.data[number - 1];
    return this;
  },
}

export default Paginator;
```

> Import

```
import Paginator from '../../helpers/Paginator';
```

> Llamada

```
const paginate = Paginator
        .data(challenges)
        .page(page);

      const { data } = paginate;
```

cuando intento cambiar a `.page(2)` me arroja lo siguiente

```
TypeError: _helpers_Paginator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.data is not a function
```

Comment: Ahí parece que data es un arreglo y luego tratas de invocarlo como función

Comment: @BetaM se me olvidaba agregar esa parte de código, listo.

Comment: Porque no simplemente usar new? tengo entendido que se puede, es tan sencillo como usar `new`, es mas, actualmente en `ES6`, ya hay clases, genericas pero hacen la misma funcion.

Comment: Hola @Riven he utilizado `export default new Paginator();` y me arroja el mismo error.

Comment: usar new para un `export` no tiene sentido con `new` me referia era a usarlo en una variable o constante, por ejemplo `const pag = new Paginator();` pero deberias pasar eso a una `class`, porque como tal no tienes una class de `ES6` si no un `Object`, `Paginator` deberia ser una `class`, el constructor que tienes no hace las vecez de constructor realmente asi como lo tienes.

Comment: Ahhh por cierto, el codigo que tienes nunca funcionara, porque con this estas haciendo referencia a propiedades no estaticas llamandolas desde un contexto inexistente (no estas guardando el objeto para almacenar sus propiedades), en su lugar el objeto se crea se usa y luego al momento de usarlo una segunda vez por `.page` ya se habra destruido. no se, se ve muy raro, a mi parecer es como si trataras de hacer un `this.this`.

Comment: @Riven he movido todo a como haz dicho, me arroja esto: `TypeError: _helpers_Paginator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a is not a constructor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He convertido tu codigo a estandares de `ES6`, son muchas cosas que explicar, asi que en su lugar dejare una referencia acerca de las clases de `ES6`, que te ayudaran a entender de manera mas detallada y mejor los cambios que he hecho:

```js
//Archivo donde exportas la clase
export default class Paginator{
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
    this.page = 0;
  }
  
  data(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
  
  page(number) {
    this.page = number;
    this.data = this.data[number - 1];
  }
}

//Archivo donde importas la clase
//import Paginator from '../../helpers/Paginator';

const paginate = new Paginator();
paginate.data(challenges)
paginate.page(page);

//NO DEBES HACER ESTO, SIMPLEMENTE ES REDUNDANTE Y ERRONEO
//No le puedes hacer destructuring a una clase de esta manera.
//const { data } = paginate;

//En su lugar simplemente crea otra instancia y usala:
const pagi = new Paginator();
```

Enlace hacia la documentación de las clases de `ES6`:

[Clases](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes)

creo que la confusion mas grande que tienes es que haz pensado que **un objeto en javascript es la instancia de una clase**, que en si es correcto, pero entonces al tener el objeto te sobra retornar los `this`, puesto que en teoria ya tendrias guardada la instancia al crearla (el objeto), asi que estos `return` sobran y solo darian posibles errores, `this` y la instancia del objeto son lo mismo:

```
data(data) {
  this.data = data;
  return this;      //Sobra
},
page(number) {
  this.page = number;
  this.data = this.data[number - 1];
  return this;      //Sobra
}
```

Comment: PD: puedes obtener la longitud de un array usando la propiedad `length`, por si depronto lo necesitas, por ejemplo para obtener la cantidad de datos contenidos en `this.data`, seria `this.data.length`.

Comment: Ahhh un punto curioso que se me olvido mencionar, estas entrando en un conflicto de nombres, si te fijas `data` es una propiedad de la clase, pero a la vez hay un metodo llamado `data`, por lo tanto habra un conflicto de nombres, debes asegurarte de cambiarle el nombre a `data()` por otra cosa, para que no entre en conflicto con tu propiedad `data`, o hacer del metodo `data` un `setter`.

Comment: recuerda que si mi respuesta te ayudo puedes darla como aceptada, y tanto la persona que pregunto como la persona que respondio ganaran puntos.